# Passing host group name in ansible-playbook command line

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I have an inventory file

example:

```
[groupa]
10.102.16.100
10.102.16.101

[groupa:vars]
app=testapp-a
env=staging

[groupb]
10.102.16.102
10.102.16.103

[groupb:vars]
app=testapp-b
env=production
```

Now if I run

```
ansible-playbook -i ./example playbook-x.yml
```

This will run for all the hosts.
Is there any way I can specify the group name in the command line itself.

I'm expecting something like

```
ansible-playbook -i ./example --group-name groupb playbook-x.yml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [--limit](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html) to specify the group like so,

```
ansible-playbook -i ./example playbook-x.yml --limit groupa
```

`hosts` field of playbook can also be used to target a specific group like,

```yaml
- hosts: groupa
  tasks:
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to target inventory groups dynamically; a simple approach is to pass the hosts as variable in the playbook.

```
---
hosts: “{{target}}”
tasks:
```

While running the playbook pass the target variable like ‘ansible-playbook playbook-x.yml -i ./example -e target=groupa’